# SSH over internet on pi 4(connectivity using RF modem )

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-4, wireless, remote

Sorry if I am asking a silly question as this is all new for me 
also read many questions here but bot find appropriate one that ans my problem

Problem: I want access pi from another network over internet for accessing files that are residing on pi so that I can made changes if needed.
I have provided network connectivity to pi using Nimbelink NL-SW-LTE-TC4NAG RF modem. And also adding a rough design of my kit .

Basically we are designing kit for providing cm level location accuracy with the help of ZEDF9P GNSS module. Please provide me solution that works for 120 number of pi(I am designing 120 kit for commercial purpose)

can anyone suggested how it can be achieved ?

PS: I know enabling ssh can work but confused with how i will do port forwarding

[image: Basic Design of kit]

Comment: Which RF modem?  Some details of your set up will be useful.

Comment: I am using Nimbelink RF modem (NL-SW-LTE-TC4NAG)(Basically we are designing an kit for cm level location accuracy with the help of ZEDF9P GNSS module) only thing I an confused is I want access my kit(pi) over internet from another network so that if i want I can made changes to some file residing on pi.

Comment: You need to add ALL relevant information to your question.  I'm not going to read a question and then work through a series of comments.

Comment: Edited,please let me know if you need some specific info.